# associative array : keep it as array or string?

Tags: php, arrays

I get this array from my DB:

```
[0] => Array (
    [currency_id] => 1
    [currency_symbol] => USD
    )
[1] => Array (
    [currency_id] => 2
    [currency_symbol] => EUR
    )
[2] => Array (
    [currency_id] => 3
    [currency_symbol] => EGP
    )
[3] => Array (
    [currency_id] => 4
    [currency_symbol] => BTC
    )
```

now my PHP code needs to get an array like this :

```
$pdocrud->tableColFormatting("currency_id", "replace",array("3" =>"EGP","1" =>"USD"));
```

Do I need to convert my array to a comma separated string  or do I have a more "direct solution"?
Thanks

Comment: what expected outcome you want ?

Comment: See this link: http://pdocrud.com/demo/pages/table-col-string-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also work.

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'currency_id' => 1,
        'currency_symbol' => 'USD',
    ),
    array(
        'currency_id' => 2,
        'currency_symbol' => 'EUR',
    ),

    array(
        'currency_id' => 3,
        'currency_symbol' => 'EGP',
    ),
    array(
        'currency_id' => 4,
        'currency_symbol' => 'BTC',
    )
);


$currency = array_column($records,'currency_symbol', 'currency_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'currency_id' => 1,
        'currency_symbol' => 'USD'
    ),
    array(
        'currency_id' => 3,
        'currency_symbol' => 'EGP'
    )
);

print_r(
    array_combine(
         array_column($arr, 'currency_id'),
         array_column($arr, 'currency_symbol')
    )
);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [1] => USD
    [3] => EGP
)
```